# Looping a variable length array with namespaces in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

My previous question[1] is related to this. I found the answer for that. Now I want to loop a variable length array with namespaces. My array:

```
<ns:array xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org">
    <value>755</value>
    <value>5861</value>
    <value>4328</value>
    <value>2157</value>
    <value>1666</value>
</ns:array>
```

My XSLT code:(have added the namespace in the root)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="number" select="ns:array" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$number">
        <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287219/looping-a-variable-length-array-in-xslt

Comment: Did my appraoch help you in any way?

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks a lot for your help. Your solution works. I have been trying this, but failed since my namespace was wrong. It should be "ns". not "ns1". Once again, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you confused yourself by introducing a variable called `number` which actually contains a node set of `value` tags. Then, as a consequence you used your variable as singe item/node which does not yield the desired result (presumingly, since you did not really tell us what you want to do with the values).

Also, I think your question does not really have anything to with namespace issues as such. You just have to make sure that the namespaces in your `select` expressions match the namespaces in your input file.

I would suggest to do without the variable and change the way you retrieve the current value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:array">

      <!-- Inside here you can work with the `value` tag as the _current node_. 
           There are two most likely ways to do this. -->

      <!-- a) Copy the whole tag to the output: -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />

      <!-- or b1) Copy the text part contained in the tag to the output: -->
      <xsl:value-of select="." />

      <!-- If you want to be on the safe side with respect to white space 
           you can also use this b2). This would handle the case that your output
           is required not to have any white space in it but your imput XML has
           some.  -->
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Meta question: Does anybody know why the syntax highlighting does not work for my code above? Looks like pretty normal XSLT to me.

Comment: @user3049576: Thanks for trying to correct my XSLT! Unfortunately, your edit was rejected because all reviewers were apparently a little sleepy and did not see the correctness of your edit. So, I did the correction myself (an author is always allowed to edit his/her post without reviewing).